# How to add actions to service?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications

I want to know in which function you should/could put the code of an actions that a service should execute? I also want to know what happens to the service when it has ran through all code. Will it just restart or will it stop? (I started it with START_STICKY)
I want to make an application that shows a notification in the notification bar when its a special time of day. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code in oncreate or onstartcommand function of a service. oncreate is called for the first time when service is not running proceeded with onstartcommand and if service is already running and again you do  startservice then onstartcommand only called. It gets killed when the app gets killed or when you kill it by stopself or stopservice. Service don't get kill itself after code completion.